# How to convert a date from android provider date call logs?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

i would like to convert a date from android provider call log. The actual date is 1341238489840.

```
int _DATE =  calls.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
String date = calls.getString(_DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the date.

```
  Date dt=new Date(1341238489840L);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you this code i have tested it

```
public class CDate {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Date date = new Date(1341238489840L);
            System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
                    .format(date));
        }
    }
```